# FileVault in cq5 with GIT repository on Windows platform

Tags: git, aem

How do we integrate filevault>GIT>Windows? I checked on their site but it is only for SVN.

Answer (score 1):

Do yourself a favor and dump filevault ASAP - especially on Windows, it's slow and unstable, and has a tendency to mess up its .vlt files and end up nuking your files.

Move towards a proper setup using maven for builds and deploys, it will save you a lot a lot of headaches in the long run. VLT should basically only be used for checking out the /lib and /apps/geometrixx, so you can look at Adobes demo (not "OOTB"!) components - they're a good reference for how *not* to do things :)

Answer (score 0):

While I would agree with snemarch about using maven instead, if you actually want to go the VLT>GIT route, it isn't too difficult, but will require some setup.

First, read the documentation of how to use the vlt tool: 
http://dev.day.com/docs/en/crx/current/how_to/how_to_use_the_vlttool.html

Essentially, what you'll do is configure vlt to checkout the directories you'll wish to manipulate and configure a sync.  This will translate the JCR into the expected file structure.  By configuring a sync, it will keep the files updated as you modify them, translating them back into the JCR.

At this point, all you need to do is configure your git project base at the same point where the JCR to FS translations are occurring.

With sync enabled, if you do a git pull to update files, it should sync them back into the JCR as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but Maven build were too long for me and not agile enough to JavaScript development. So I started writing [Vlt sublime plugin](https://github.com/tomalec/Sublime-Text-2-Vlt-Plugin).

Currently, I have just simple GIT repo on my file system, then work on it with [Sublime](http://www.sublimetext.com/) and it commits to SVN automatically on save.

As @snemarch wrote VLT is great tool to nuke your files ;) so still sometimes you need to call some `vlt update`, `vlt resolve` manually (from Sublime command palette). Plus, plugin is still in very early stage (I'm noob in Python ;) ).

Anyway plugin gives my comfortable `ctrl+s`, `F5` flow, without waiting for any build, and frequent commits to local repo, helps to avoid huge VLT mess.